# Find the current user language

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

How can I tell the current user language in a [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) program?

I need this to show a form in an appropriate language.

Comment: @brettdj I reckon the more generic `excel` is always a useful tag as well as it makes future searches easier.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My initial code (utilising this [vbforum code](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=610740)) assumed that Windows and Excel share a common language - likely but not bulletproof.

*updated*

The revised code:

1. Returns the Locale ID (LCID).
2. Looks up the LCID from this [msft link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664).
3. Parses the LCID using a [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) to get the language.

**Sample output on my machine below**

The code will let the user know if there are any errors in accessing the LCID website, or in parsing the country name.

[image]

```
    Sub GetXlLang()
        Dim lngCode As Long
        lngCode = Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
        MsgBox "Code is: " & lngCode & vbNewLine & GetTxt(lngCode)
    End Sub

    Function GetTxt(ByVal lngCode) As String
        Dim objXmlHTTP As Object
        Dim objRegex As Object
        Dim objRegMC As Object
        Dim strResponse As String
        Dim strSite As String

        Set objXmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        strSite = "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664"

        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        With objXmlHTTP
            .Open "GET", strSite, False
            .Send
            If .Status = 200 Then strResponse = .ResponseText
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        strResponse = Replace(strResponse, "</td><td>", vbNullString)
        Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        With objRegex
            .Pattern = "><td>([a-zA-Z- ]+)[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}" & lngCode                    
            If .Test(strResponse) Then
                Set objRegMC = .Execute(strResponse)
                GetTxt = objRegMC(0).submatches(0)
            Else
                GetTxt = "Value not found from " & strSite
            End If
        End With
        Set objRegex = Nothing
        Set objXmlHTTP = Nothing
        Exit Function
ErrHandler:
        If Not objXmlHTTP Is Nothing Then Set objXmlHTTP = Nothing
        GetTxt = strSite & " unable to be accessed"
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does what I was looking for. I replaced LOCALE_SNATIVELANGNAME = &H4 with LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME = &H59 to get a local independent value.

Comment: Can you people guide me about how to show appropriate language after identifying the location...if you have different resource files...then how do make these files in VBA editor of excel...???

Answer (score 11):

```
dim lang_code as long
lang_code = Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But I just get a number. How can I find out the real language this numbers stands for?

Comment: You can find a list of LCIDs here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664

Comment: For reference [learn.microsoft.com page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Office.MsoLanguageID)

Answer (score 1):

This is another variation of the code posted by brettdj

```
Sub Test_GetLocale_UDF()
Dim lngCode As Long

lngCode = Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
MsgBox "Code Is: " & lngCode & vbNewLine & GetLocale(lngCode)
End Sub

Function GetLocale(ByVal lngCode) As String
Dim html            As Object
Dim http            As Object
Dim htmlTable       As Object
Dim htmlRow         As Object
Dim htmlCell        As Object
Dim url             As String

Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
url = "https://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php"

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    With http
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        If .Status = 200 Then html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set htmlTable = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)

For Each htmlRow In htmlTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    For Each htmlCell In htmlRow.Children
        If htmlCell.innerText = CStr(lngCode) Then
            GetLocale = htmlRow.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText
            Exit For
        End If
    Next htmlCell
Next htmlRow

If GetLocale = "" Then GetLocale = "Value Not Found From " & url

Exit Function
ErrHandler:
If Not http Is Nothing Then Set http = Nothing
GetLocale = url & " Unable To Be Accessed"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Case Application.International(xlApplicationInternational.xlCountryCode) 
   Case 1: Call MsgBox("English") 
   Case 33: Call MsgBox("French") 
   Case 49: Call MsgBox("German") 
   Case 81: Call MsgBox("Japanese") 
End Select
```

Straight out of here: https://bettersolutions.com/vba/macros/region-language.htm

Relevant Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlapplicationinternational

Answer (score -1):

VBA `Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)` gets only Microsoft Office Access or Microsoft Excel User interface Language. But does not reflect the Windows System display language used for Windows Display, every thing as `MsgBox()` buttons etc.

If user changes his Windows Display language via Windows Control Panel, this Application level setting will not change. In which case, we can use this Kernel dll function to get the new [LCID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/70feba9f-294e-491e-b6eb-56532684c37f) (Microsoft Language Code IDentifier, 1036=French, 1033=English, ...), with this code in a VBA Module:

```
Private Declare Function GetUserDefaultUILanguage Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long

Public Function winGetUserDefaultUILanguage()
  winGetUserDefaultUILanguage = GetUserDefaultUILanguage()
End Function
```

Then you can call the public function `winGetUserDefaultUILanguage()` every where in your VBA code to get Windows LCID.

The kernel dll function `GetUserDefaultUILanguage()` will reflect the changement via Windows Display Language ID.

---

For example, as I've French Windows display language, LCID=1036, my Office is also in French (LCID=1036),

[image]

VBA Debugger Console:

[image]

---

Now we switch to English Windows display language via Control Panel (LCID=1033 for English), but my Office language ID remains unchanged (LCID=1036):

[image]

VBA Debugger Console:

[image]

From LCID, you can further get Language Tag, Language Name from [Microsoft API documents here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/70feba9f-294e-491e-b6eb-56532684c37f) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c?redirectedfrom=MSDN).