# Formulas within Named Range changes when opened in foreign language version of Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

When opened in an English language version of Excel, the following definition for a named range works just fine:

```
=OFFSET('Summary Data'!$B$9,0,0,TotalStops+1,SummaryDataColumns)
```

However, when the same worksheet (created using an English language version of Excel) is open using a Portuguese language version of Excel the formula in the named range is changed to:

```
=DESLOC('Summary Data'!$B$9;0;0;TotalStops+1;SummaryDataColumns)
```

To my understanding "DESLOC" is the correct translation for OFFSET, but all of commas in the formula have been replaced with semi-colons. Now anytime that the named range is referred to in vba code, the code execution fails at that point.

Just for reference, the call that references the named range is of the form:

```
thisworkbook.Names("dbSummaryData").RefersToRange
```

Comment: I believe it's a bug. you can use evaluate with the refersto property or refer to the range by name instead `Sheets("Summary Data").Range("dbSummaryData")`

Answer (score 0):

This link may provide a better explanation, [Find the current user language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588728/excel-2010-vba-find-the-current-user-language)

You should be able to put a check into your VBA code on what language is selected and if its other than English it will swap semi-colon for comma then execute.