# Internationalize excel formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

There is some way to type internationalized formulas on excel macros??

Right now im doing some like this:

```
If (languageCode = 1033) Then
  'type formula in english
  sheet.cell(r,c).Value = "=IF(A1=B1, "i18n", "#error")"
Else
  'type formula in another language
  sheet.cell(r,c).Value = "=SE(A1=B1, "i18n", "#erro")"
End If
```

Im using this logic because the client's excel is in a different language than mine, but the formula is realy big, and there are many other languages to cover.. so im not liking the way it going. :(
I did some reseacrh but with no satisfactory answers.

*This is my very first question so, sorry if I made some typo or format mistake.*

Comment: Are you asking for a self-translating formula? I do not think there is any way to do this...

Comment: I think Excel should translate if you use `.Formula` instead of `.Value`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588728/excel-2010-vba-find-the-current-user-language - the Excel language may differ from Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accorcing to [this article](http://vantedbits.blogspot.com/2010/10/excel-vba-tip-translate-formulas.html) vba works internally with English, and Excel translates to the destination language at runtime. You should be able to do this with the `formula` property of the cell instead of the `.value`.

```
sheet.cell(r,c).Formula = "=IF(A1=B1, "i18n", "#error")"
```

See also [Internationally Valid Excel Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13247771/3198973).

Comment: In addition, it is possible to see or set the local language version of the formula using the `FormulaLocal` property.