# How to get the user's language in Excel with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get the user's language in Excel through VBA, as far as Excel does not automatically translate Pivot tables and I am searching within a Pivot with `VBA`.

Just found out that in German the Pivot looks like this:

[image]

While in English it is like this:

[image]

I can think about an option, writing a `=VLOOKUP()` formula in Excel and checking whether the words are actually "Vlookup" or whether they are `=SVERWEIS()` and based on the result decide whether it is German or English.

Anyway, this looks too "ugly". Are there any better ideas?

Comment: Maybe [`Application.LanguageSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.languagesettings)? Haven't actually tried it.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588728/find-the-current-user-language

Comment: `Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDInstall)`

Comment: @BigBen, @brax - `Application.LanguageSettings` returns 438 and the answer is from 2011, checking a website, does not work (and I really do not want to check a website from Excel...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option would be to check the [`Application.International`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.international) property. For example making use of `xlCountryCode`:

```
Application.International(xlCountryCode)
```

Answer (score 5):

After testing with 2 Excels (English & German), what has been proved to work is:

`Application.International(xlCountryCode)`

returning the following for the different Excel countries versions:

- US - 1
- Germany - 49
- France - 33
- Spain - 34
- Russia - 7
- Others - https://countrycode.org.

**Note - the following does not work and is dangerous:**

- `Application.LanguageSettings.LanguagePreferredForEditing(msoLanguageIDEnglishUS)`
- `Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDInstall)`
- `Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDExeMode)`

Probably it looks **not** at the language of your excel, but at the language of your Windows, which *can* be different, as in my own PC:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try, please:

```
Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDInstall)
```

or

```
Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDExeMode)
```

in case they return differently...

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. Take a look at what I am getting with my home PC, which unfortunately has German Excel and English Windows - https://imgur.com/a/1TvsyR7

Comment: I know it was me in the comments, who said it should work... But I have not tested it on the other PC.