# How to detect COMA or DOT as decimal for multilanguage excel-vba macros

Tags: excel, vba, regional-settings

I made a excel with vba that should work regardless the local setting for comas and dots, now, I have manually this detection and load one or another macro depending the user.

how can I detect this setting on vba ?

Comment: maybe `Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDInstall)` can be useful here?  Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62639517/how-to-get-the-users-language-in-excel-with-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After readiing post [How to get the user's language in Excel with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62639517/how-to-get-the-users-language-in-excel-with-vba) I think you could use:

`Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)` will return the character used as Decimal Separator.

`Application.International(xlThousandsSeparator)` will return the character used as thousands separator.

My test:

```
Sub test()

'Spanish Excel with spanish setup
'My decimal separator is comma
'Thousands separators is dot

Debug.Print "Decimal: " & Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)
Debug.Print "Thousands: " & Application.International(xlThousandsSeparator)
End Sub
```

Output I get:

[image]